# Password change or reset applies to wrong address

Tags: support, bug, login

I have two email addresses associated with my StackOverflow account: an old one which was used to create the account, and a new one. When I log out and I try to log back in, the new email address is always rejected, while the old email address still works.

When I try to run password recovery with the new address, I receive an email with a reset password link, which I follow. The page actually says "Recover account for [old email address]", even though I asked for a recovery with the new address. I do reset the password anyway. But the same thing happens again; the old address still works (with the new password), and the new one still doesn't (old or new passwords alike).

If I log in with the old address, and go to my profile settings, I can also try to change the password for both addresses. However, the change password link is the same for both addresses, and when following the links, both say "Change password for [old email address]".

It seems the change password logic is always updating the password for the old address, even when attempting to change the password for the new address.

Comment: Why not remove the other login method from your account, if the email address is no longer used?

Comment: @Larnu I still have access to the old address. I am reluctant to remove it until I am confident that I can log back in with the new one!